# Wrong float division result in c

Tags: c

```
void four_corners(float A[rows][columns]){
int up,down,right,left;
int x=2;
A[0][0]=(float)(up+left)/(float)(x);
A[0][19]=(float)(up+right)/(float)(x);
A[9][0]=(float)(down+left)/(float)(x);
A[9][19]=(float)(down+right)/(float)(x);}
```

When i insert the four values in an array i do not get the correct value of them. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Cast first and divide then. You are doing an integer division here

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi, he already is casting first.  He is performing floating-point, not integer, division.  Even if cast operators did not have higher precedence than the division operator, the cast operators in the denominators would have the needed effect.

Comment: In the code you present, `up`, `down`, `right`, and `left` are all uninitialized.  How, then, can you have any particular expectation for what values are stored in the array?

Comment: @JohnBollinger There is scanf function in the beginning of the programm where the user gives the values of up,down,right,left.

Comment: How can it? They are local to `void four_corners()`.

Comment: @vasilistheod, no, there is not.  That is, no `scanf()` call in some other function can be setting values for the *local* variables of `four_corners()`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks a lot for your help mate.I solved my problem!:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define W 10
#define H 20

void four_corners(float A[W][H], int up, int down, int right, int left) {
    int x = 2;
    A[0][0] = (float)(up + left) / (float)(x);
    A[0][19] = (float)(up + right) / (float)(x);
    A[9][0] = (float)(down + left) / (float)(x);
    A[9][19] = (float)(down + right) / (float)(x);
}

void print_board(float A[W][H]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < W; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < H; j++) {
            printf("%.1f ", A[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    float A[W][H];
    memset(A, 0, W * H * sizeof(float));
    four_corners(A, 1, 2, 3, 4);
    print_board(A);
    getch();
}
```

Basically the problem you're having in your code is `up`, `down`, `right`, `left` are all of them local variables and they're just visible to the `four_corners` functions. You think they're been initialized properly when doing scanf in another scope but they're actually not. If you want them to be visible to the scanf's scope and `four_corners` scope either you pass them as arguments to the function or you make them global. I'd suggest you read more about [C scopes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm) and this will become cristal clear to you. Happy coding!